# Probability that one of machines is working all 5 days

Tags: probability, statistics

There are $2$ copy machines

The probability that machine $A$ will work all day long is $P(A) = 0.9.$

The probability that machine $B$ will work all day long is $P(B) = 0.85.$

A working week is 5 days.

What is the probability that at least one of the machines will work all day in $5$ days?

The answer is $0.328,$ but I cant find the way to get it can someone put me on the road?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties that you are encountering.

Comment: ''the machines will work all day in 5 days'' does that mean exactly one day it will work whole day? or it will work whole day in all the 5 days?

Comment: Are you sure about the answer? It seems that the probability should be higher.

Answer (score 1):

First work out the probability that at least one of the two machines will work on any single day.  $P(A\cup B)$

Next, what is the probability of this happening five days in a row?

---

Hint: the answer is *not*  $0.328$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is intuitively wrong. The probability that at least one of the machines work every day should be higher.

The probability that during a given day at least one of the machines works is $$0.9+0.85-0.9\times0.85=0.985.$$

The probability that this event repats $5$ times independently is $$0.985^5=0.927216502...$$

I assumed that if a machine breaks down then it gets fixed overnite.

The other possibility: we assume that if a machine breaks down then nobody fixes it. Even then the answer is not what the OP claims.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the event that the machine $A$ works all days in a five days  and let $Y$ be the event that the machine $B$ works all days in a five days.
Then $X\cup Y$ is a event that at least one machine work all days in a five days.
$$P(X\cup Y) =P(X) +P(Y) -P(X\cap Y) =P(A)^5 +P(B)^5 -(P(A)P(B))^5 $$

Comment: That is 0.227808237...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure out the probability that at least one of the machines will work on one day.

You can do this by following this line of thinking: The probability that at least one machine is working is equal to the sum of the probabilities of the following events:

> Machine A works, but machine B does not (probability $0.9\cdot 0.15$).
>
> Machine A does not work, but machine B does (probability $0.10\cdot 0.85$).
>
> Both machine A and B Work (probability $0.9\cdot 0.85$).

This gives a total probability of 0.985 that at least one of the machines will work on any given day.

Now, the probability that at least one of the machines work on 5 consecutive days is then $0.985^5 = 0.927$.

I don't know where your $0.328$ came from.